# Passing multiple parameters to AJAX JQuery with PHP variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass 2 values to a `AJAX` `JQuery` function.

My function is triggered `onChange` of a drop down list that which gets data from a DB and runs through a `while` loop and outputs it with `PHP`, it looks like this:

```
$dropDown = "<label for='drop_down_list'>Drop Down: </label>
                <select name='drop_down_list' id='drop_down_list' onChange='getInfo(this.value, ". $val2 .")'>
                    <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>Options</option><br/>
                    " . $dropDownOptions . "
                </select></br>";

echo $dropDown;
```

Here I am trying to send the selected options value, as well as a value I have in a PHP variable (which does have a value because I echo it out elsewhere).

My `getinfo` function looks like this:

```
function getInfo(val1, val2) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "get_info.php",
    data: 'value1='+val1+'&value2'+val2,

    success: function(data){
            $("#info").html(data);
    }
   });
};
```

I try to output the values I return from get_info.php like this:

```
$value1 = $_POST['value1'];
$value2 = $_POST['value2'];

echo "First Value: " .$value1;
echo "<br>";
echo "Second Value: " .$value2;
```

My output is:

```
First Value: 1
Second Value:
```

I have error reporting on and I am getting an undefined error on `$value2` so I think somewhere that PHP variable is not passing properly, I'm not quite sure if that is how I am supposed to properly pass the PHP value I need, am I doing something wrong here?

How can I pass my `PHP` variable into an `AJAX` `JQuery` function and and get the output the values properly?

example:

```
First Value: 1
Second Value: 2
```

Comment: Looks like you need an equals sign after value 2:  

    data: 'value1='+val1+'&value2='+val2,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed an equal `=` in your js function:

```
function getInfo(val1, val2) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "get_info.php",
    data: 'value1='+val1+'&value2='+val2,

    success: function(data){
        $("#info").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: ha, yep that worked, good catch, thanks a lot, I can't accept the answer for another 7 minutes but I will when I can :)

Answer (score 3):

Try send each parameter separated

```
function getInfo(val1, val2) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "get_info.php",
    data: {
        'value1': val1,
        'value2': val2
    },
    success: function(data){
       $("#info").html(data);
    }
}
```

If you have many parameters, you should create a dynamic json object with your values and then send it like this:

```
data: your_json_object
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either output it as a json-string and deal with it in js, or you could output like
 `echo $value1."#".$value2;` 
and split on "#" in the javascript.